# Having trouble forwarding ports on uncommon south american router(telecom)

Tags: windows-10, router, internet

[image]

That is the router menu where i imagine the port-forwarding is setup, the thing is, it looks nothing like tutorials in port forwarding look like online and I dont know what to put where.

This is what im trying to do with port forwarding:
https://forum.plutonium.pw/topic/7/custom-games-with-friends

"The host of the game needs to forward 4976 UDP in order for others to connect."-I dont know where that number is supposed to go.

for reference, this is a random port-forwarding tutorial video ive been using to guide myself:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=273l4cyLZA4

If additional screenshots are needed Im eager to send the most I can but I dont want to bloat the post with like 10 screenshots of every menu so please request them, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I found [a manual](https://setuprouter.com/router/huawei/hg8245/manual-165.pdf). On page 325, the dialog looks quite different from what you see. Your ISP may have accidentally broken the firmware when customizing it. Do the predefined applications work?

Comment: ok, I found the exact menu you mention, what next, just the usual things the tutorial mentions?

Comment: It could always just be a different firmware version. Some manufacturers like to change _everything_ up every now and then.

Comment: Can you tell us what the first two octets of your wan connections ip address are? No need for the full, example: 102.232.x.x